I figured out how to use WASM with nextjs via emscripten, but my solution is really stupid
I wanted to call a C++ function from my next.js component. Using emscripten and the -sENVIRONMENT='web' -sMODULARIZE=1 flags, I compiled the C++ into main.js and main.wasm. I tried running it from a component:
import Solver from '@/wasm/main';

export default function WasmComponent() {
    const handleClick = async () => {
        const Module = await Solver();
        const test = Module.cwrap("myfunction", "string", ["string"]);
        console.log(test("test"));
    }
    
    return (
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>Call the WASM Function!</Button>
    )

}

The console kept giving me an error saying it couldn't find http://localhost/_next/static/chunks/main.wasm. Obviously I needed to load the .wasm file into the webpack, but I don't understand webpacks that well. After an hour or two of fiddling with next.config.mjs nothing would work and I was beginning to get a headache.
Alternatively, I couldn't figure out how to tell emscripten to choose a different filepath to read the .wasm file. It would always look in http://localhost/_next/static/chunks/, and I couldn't find any options to configure it otherwise.
So my genius theory: if I serve the file statically from a path called http://localhost/_next/static/chunks/main.wasm, then technically it will be in the right location. I manually created these directories in my next.js project's public folder, and it actually worked! The wasm function runs.
But it's obviously not what I'm supposed to do. So. . .  what's the right way?

Starting with Next.js 11, you can import WASM files either by importing them with next/dynamic components or using WebAssembly APIs.

I eventually found the answer in this blog post. If I add the flag -sSINGLE_FILE=1 to the compilation, emscripten only generates a single .js file which has the .wasm file within it. So I don't need to figure out how to load the .wasm file.
